# Create a Java class from a groovy test file in IntelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea, groovy, tdd

Trying to do TDD in a java project using groovy tests, I need to generate java classes on the fly (<kbd>Alt</kbd>`+`<kbd>Enter</kbd> from the test on the name of a class I want to introduce -> *Create class* -> Select the java main package as *Target destination*).
The problem is that, even if the *Target destination* is a java source directory, IntelliJ generates a **groovy class**.

Is there any way to quickly generate a **Java class**, instead?

Comment: Just to clarify, you trying to generate Java test class for Java class but IntelliJ generate Groovy test class instead, right ?

Comment: @AntonDozortsev yes, exactly.

Comment: @AntonDozortsev sorry, I misread your comment. I'm trying to generate a Java class from a groovy test.

Comment: Check updates from my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the current version of IntelliJ IDEA (2016.2.4) the only solution I found is to generate a groovy class (<kbd>Alt</kbd>`+`<kbd>Enter</kbd>`| Create class` from the test) and then convert it to Java (`Refactor | Convert to Java`).
To make it faster I also added a shortcut for `Convert to Java`: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> was the best available option for me.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like *now* it's not possible.

This **[guide](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/tutorial-test-driven-development.html)** is exactly for this TDD workflow and there are no mentions about it.

Also I made research through **[IntelliJ's issues](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA)** and didn't find any similar task.

And finally I post **[feature request](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-162682)** for that.

Comment: Sorry for misreading you comment, but I'm not generating the test class, but the classes that I introduce when writing the tests (and I want to generate them on the fly using Alt + Enter)

Comment: Thanks! Meanwhile I found a workaround: create a groovy class and then convert it to java (Refactor -> Convert to Java). I also added a shortcut for it.